# Python - Server and browser-client

Tags: python, browser, client, server

I have written a python server that does a task depending on the input given by the user through a client. Unfortunately, this requires the user to use the terminal.

I'd like the user to use a browser instead to send the data to the server. How would I go on about this?
Does anyone here have suggestions? Perhaps even an example?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Which kind of server did you build? A simple TCP echo server? You might want to finish that sentence starting with "Unfortunately, this". Other than that, you might want to read about protocols, start with TCP, UDP. Then, you read about HTTP. You will learn that browsers use HTTP to communicate with web servers. You will learn that HTTP works on top of TCP. Then it will be clear to you that what you need is a server supporting HTTP, for making it responsive to browser requests. Warning: complex topic, do not expect to get a deep understanding within a couple of days.

Comment: I know about TCP/UDP, my server currently accepts TCP sockets.

The question was more about what kind of modules are available for me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very subjective question and depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve but if you want to write a program with an embedded http server then you could use either [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) or [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). I've spent some time with both and found that Tornado is a bit cleaner and easier to write a web api with, but Twisted is more versatile if you want to handle different types of network connections.

Comment: The site wouldn't let me post another link (lack of rep) but there are other solutions on the python wiki you might want to look at as well:[https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServers)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question for future reference or other people with similar requests.

All of the requirements for this can be found in the standard module **BaseHTTPServer**